# “Like” condition using multiple values seperated by comma using Stored Procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a sample query with the output in the screenshot below.

[image]

But I am supposed to get the same output with the query written in a single line using `Like` condition. I have tried my best and also attached what I have tried below:

[image]

Comment: i am not sure if you are going to get the help you needed with the details in questions.here is good way to start asking question..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
WHERE
    a.languages LIKE '%' + @languages + '%'
ORDER BY
    a.tid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your data using comma , and then select the result as table

and then using following command , ( where a.language in (__)  )

here is an example of split and selection.

http://littleprograming.blogspot.com/2012/10/sql-server-string-split.html